# Get full model instance from DisplayTemplates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Inside a DisplayTemplate I can always access the value of the property I want to render by accessing `ViewData.Model`.
Is there a way to access the instance of the model that the property I'm rendering belongs to from inside the template?
For example:

```
public class IndexModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [UIHint("Value")]
    public double? Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then inside the Index.cshtml I have:

```
@model TestMVC3.Models.Home.IndexModel

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Value)
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to access the instance of type IndexModel (that I could access from Index.cshtml using the Model property), from the Value.cshtml DisplayTemplate

Comment: Can't understand your question...!!

Comment: added a more explicit example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: ViewContext.Controller.ViewData.Model